# Java Stream .map capitalize first letter only

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to sort my list alphabetically and also capitalize the first letter of each name.

When I do toUpperCase, it capitalizes every letter. If I were to print it without using `.map`, I would do (`topNames2017.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + topNames2017.substring(1)`)  which works fine, but I don't know how to apply it here

```
List<String> topNames2017 = Arrays.asList(
            "Amelia",
            "Olivia",
            "emily",
            "Isla",
            "Ava",
            "oliver",
            "Jack",
            "Charlie",
            "harry",
            "Jacob"
    );


      topNames2017
            .stream()
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Do you mean `.map(name -> name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1))`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use a lambda to get your current attempt to work, example:

```
.map(name -> name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1))
```

The `name` identifier above represents the current string passed to the `map` operation.

Alternatively, it can also be done like this:

```
.map(name -> Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) + name.substring(1))
```

If you want to maintain the use of method reference then you can define your own function like this:

```
static String capitaliseFirstLetter(String name){
      return name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
}
```

Now, you can do:

```
topNames2017.stream()
            .map(Main::capitaliseFirstLetter) // replace Main with the class containing the capitaliseFirstLetter method
            .sorted()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Apache Commons, I would suggest [`WordUtils.capitalize(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-) like

```
topNames2017.stream()
        .map(WordUtils::capitalize)
        .sorted()
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

If you can't use that, then you *might* do something like

```
topNames2017.stream()
        .map(x -> x.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1))
        .sorted()
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

In either case, if you are sorting, make sure to use `forEachOrdered`.

Comment: Plus 1 for using forEachOrdered

Answer (score 3):

Other answers tell you to use one of the following:

```
name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1)
Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) + name.substring(1)
StringUtils.capitalize(name) // Apache Commons Lang
WordUtils.capitalize(name) // Apache Commons Lang (deprecated)
```

While those all work for Unicode characters in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), there are letters in the Supplementary Planes that won't be capitalized that way. For reference, letters in the Supplementary Planes exist in the following Blocks:

- [`Deseret`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/deseret/list.htm) (U+10400 to U+1044F)
- [`Old Hungarian`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/old_hungarian/list.htm) (U+10C80 to U+10CFF)
- [`Warang Citi`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/warang_citi/list.htm) (U+118A0 to U+118FF)

You should also use `toTitleCase`, not `toUpperCase`. This makes a difference for the following characters (showing lowercase, titlecase, and uppercase):

- [`LATIN LETTER DZ WITH CARON`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c5/index.htm): ǆ ǅ Ǆ
- [`LATIN LETTER DZ`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01f2/index.htm): ǳ ǲ Ǳ
- [`LATIN LETTER LJ`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c8/index.htm): ǉ ǈ Ǉ
- [`LATIN LETTER NJ`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01cb/index.htm): ǌ ǋ Ǌ

Most people don't care about the above, but a full implementation of "capitalize first letter only" should take them into consideration.

Something like this would do:

```
static String capitalizeFirstLetter(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty())
        return s;
    int codePoint = s.codePointAt(0);
    int codePointTitle = Character.toTitleCase(codePoint);
    if (codePointTitle == codePoint)
        return s; // Nothing to capitalize
    return new String(new int[] { codePointTitle }, 0, 1)
         + s.substring(s.offsetByCodePoints(0, 1));
}
```

You then use that instead of `String::toUpperCase`:

```
.map(MyClass::capitalizeFirstLetter)
```

Comment: Apart from the perfect explanation, additional kudos for the only answer (excluding 3rd party libs) (at the time of this comment) that does not crash on an empty string.

Comment: @mtj It also doesn't create a new string if the input is already capitalized. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Or simply use apache-commons StringUtil.capitalize()
I that it's just good to know about it.

```
.map(StringUtils::capitalize)
```

More here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Task1c {

    public static void main (String args[]){

            List<String> topNames2017 = Arrays.asList(
                    "Amelia", 
                    "Olivia", 
                    "emily", 
                    "Isla", 
                    "Ava", 
                    "oliver", 
                    "Jack",
                    "Charlie", 
                    "harry", 
                    "Jacob"
            );
    topNames2017
        .stream()
        .map(name->{return Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0))+name.substring(1);})
        .sorted()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```